# Is it possible to test an object composed of different objects using GMock?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

The title is a little confusing, so let me explain.

I have the following code:
File.cpp

```
bool Foo::MyFunction()
{

    struct myStruct;

    FirstObject firstObject;
    {
        firstObject.setFirstValue(myStruct.Criticality);
        firstObject.setSecondValue(myStruct.Distance_X, myStruct.Distance_Y);
        firstObject.setThirdValue(myStruct.Distance_Z);
    }

    SecondObject secondObject;
    {
        secondObject .setFirstValue(myStruct.Criticality);
        secondObject .setSecondValue(myStruct.Distance_X, myStruct.Distance_Y);
        secondObject .setThirdValue(myStruct.Distance_Z);
    }

    TargetObject package;
    package.setFirstObject(firstObject);
    package.setSecondObject(secondObject );

    setDataPackage(package);

}
```

File.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
MyFunction();

private:
    template <typename T>
    void setDataPackage(T& package)
    {
        if (mDataConnector != nullptr)
        {             
            mDataConnector->dataUpdated(package);             
        }
        else
        {
            //other stuff
        }
        setDataPackage_Override(package);
    }
}
```

As you can see my function is a template so the only way to mock it and use it for my test, was to declare another function (setDataPackage_Override), that will be called inside, with the right type of argument.

The mocked class:

```
class MockFoo : public Foo
{
 public:

    MOCK_METHOD1(setDataPackage_Override,   void (AnotherClass::FirstTypeOfPackage& package)); 
    MOCK_METHOD1(setDataPackage_Override,   void (AnotherClass::SecondTypeOfPackage& package)); 
    MOCK_METHOD1(setDataPackage_Override,   void (AnotherClass::ThirdTypeOfPackage& package)); 


};
```

What I need to test is that every field of the package is set correctly.
I will set all the values of the structure in the beginning, and I want to check that the content of the package is what I set.
My problem is that I do not know how to go all the way to the values ( e.g myStruct.Criticality ) as they are not set directly in my package, but first set in an object and then fed to the package.

I had a similar example:

```
bool Foo::MyFunction()
{

        struct myStruct;
        int value = myStruct.targetValue;
        TargetObject package;
        package.setValue(value );

        setDataPackage(package);
}
```

This I tested like this:

I filled my struct with values, for the sake of this test, let's say myStruct.targetValue equals 20

```
EXPECT_CALL( *mockFoo, setDataPackage(
    testing::Property( &Class::getValue, 
    testing::Eq(int (20)))));
```

Mention:
All my set functions have their get function implemented.

Is there a way to test my package using the Gmock framework?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a way for this question.

What I did was to declare separate matchers that would first test the correct data inside each "second" objects:

```
MATCHER_P(checkGetCriticality_getFirstValue,      value , " ") { return (arg.Class::FirstObject::getFirstValue()      == value); }
MATCHER_P(checkGetPointFront_getSecondValue,       value , " ") { return (arg.Class::FirstObject::getSecondValue()       == value); }
MATCHER_P(checkGetDistanceRearZ_getThirdValue,    value , " ") { return (arg.Class::FirstObject::getThirdValue()    == value); }
```

And then pass these matchers and check the "main" object:

```
EXPECT_CALL( *mockFoo, setDataPackage(Matcher<AnotherClass::FirstTypeOfPackage&>( 
AllOf(  
//getEgoOneDtrObj
(testing::Property(&Class:TargetObject::getValue, checkGetCriticality_getFirstValue      (uint8_t(100)))),       
(testing::Property(&Class:TargetObject::getValue, checkGetPointFront_getSecondValue      (double(200)))),
(testing::Property(&Class:TargetObject::getValue, checkGetDistanceRearZ_getThirdValue    (double(8190))))
))));
```

Hope this will help someone.